# Is it possible to communicate to a websocket located in a different server than the one that html5 website renders?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, ip, hardware

What I want to do is to communicate a HTML5 website to a hardware device. What I have seen is that the only way could be using WebSockets, or maybe WebRTC, through a WiFi network.
Is that right?

I have not seen anything with Bluetooth yet... Not even in the HTML5 specs...

In order to establish a WebSocket connection in my own hardware, I would need to run a web server on it that supports WebSockets like in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahIJUkbq1JA

So, I want to be able to make a bidirectional interface between some little box, with a web server, and a HTML 5 app located in an iPad for example but the server where the HTML app is rendering from has to be in the internet (not in my little box). Is that possible?

Are there any examples of that in embedded systems?

Answer (score 0):

When you have control over the server, it is possible. It is recommended for the server to check the Origin-header of any websocket connections to make sure that no unauthorized website uses the service, but this is server-sided, purely optional and the server can decide freely which origins to trust.

But keep in mind that the websocket protocol is not easy to implement and not that well-supported yet. But there are other options for real-time communication between web-browsers and servers, like XmlHttpRequest. Which option is preferable depends on how your network protocol works. In general, XmlHttpRequest is better-suited for a pull-protocol while WebSockets are better for a push-protocol.

Comment: But, I meant a browser that render the pages from a server and a websocket connection from the browser to another server (for example, located in a embedded system). I think you did not understand what I meant.

Comment: @leo2_uru I think I did understand you, and as I described it is not a problem at all. You can load a website from domain A and create a WS connection to domain B as long as the WS server on domain B accepts A as origin-header.

Comment: Sorry, I was the one who did not undertand... I see what you meant. How can I find if my web server would support that? Does it have a specific denomination? Where can I read more about it? I didn't know that the domain A would be included, as header, in the message to the Domain B server. What I am thinking is something like a web server implemented in a PIC microcontroller, for example, and a HTML5 app running in an iOS device where I can send parameters to the PIC (to turn on/off lights for example) and send replies back to the iDevice...